# How to translate this sql query to mongodb?

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, translation

Does anyone know how to translate these 2 queries from PostgreSQL to MongoDB? I don't have any idea from MongoDB but I have to use these 2 lines in my script.

```
SELECT genres,startYear,COUNT(*) 
FROM title_basics 
GROUP BY genres, "startYear";

SELECT genres,COUNT(genres) 
FROM title_basics 
GROUP BY genres 
ORDER BY COUNT(genres) DESC;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

These are the queries you can use with the mongodb driver inside your code.

```
db.titles_basics.aggregate([
{"$group" : {genres:"$startYear", count:{$sum:1}}}
])

 db.titles_basics.aggregate([
{"$group" : {genres:"$startYear", count:{$sum:1}}} ,{ $sortByCount: "$genres" }
])
```

Hope this works and if doesn't try explaining your question a little bit more.
Your question is very poorly explained and what i got from it i posted my answer for it. GOOD LUCK :)